# Best parallel algorithm for detecting cycles in a undirect graph

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, openmp, graph-algorithm

I want to detect cycles in an undirected graph such that I can find the minimum spanning tree (in particular I want to use Kruskal algorithm). Since I want to parallelize the code, I was wondering which algorithm is the best, Depth-first search of union-find algorithm? 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: @Betelqeuse kruskal being greedy algorithm where lower cost edge is considered before others hence i dont think of any way to parallelize it.

Comment: so is only Prim parallelizable? Do you know other algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of all three MST algorithms only [Boruvka's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka%27s_algorithm) MST algorithm is easily parallelizable whereas the kruskal and prims are sequential greedy algorithms hence there is minimum scope for parallel implementation of them.

**Note:** It is a research topic to achieve efficient parallel boruvka might find some papers